# Sorting a dictionary by key but also display the key's value - Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains a leader-board. They keys in the dictionary are names and the key definition is the user's score.

For example if I print the dictionary it outputs:

```
{'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Zanggangwang': [3], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]}
```

I want to sort this in alphabetical order so when I print it. It displays like this:

```
{'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9], 'Zanggangwang': [3]}
(The keys are alphabetical)
```

I tried using:

```
sortednames=sorted(c.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())
```

although this just printed the key names in alphabetical order rather than the key name and the definition;

```
['Bill', 'T', 'Tom', 'Zanggangwang']
```

How can I sort this in alphabetical order and still have it display the scores?

I am rather new to python and would appreciate a good explanation to help solutions you may have to recommend.

## Update

In response to Hai Vu, I tried using the method you suggested:

```
#And then I tried printing the list although it seems to print:
deque(['Zanggangwang', 'Tom', 'T'], maxlen=3)
```

What have I done wrong?
I have looked at ordereDict and this seems like a good method to attempt although I ma not sure how I could implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is unordered, meaning the keys are not sorted. If your goal is to print the dictionary sorted by key, then consider using the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module, for example:

```
import pprint

d = {'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Zanggangwang': [3], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]}
pprint.pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9], 'Zanggangwang': [3]}
```

Note that if the dictionary is long, then the output might spans several lines. If you are looking to print to a file, then consider [pprint.pformat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pformat)

## Update

If you want to keep track of the last 3 keys appended, you will have to do that yourself because a dictionary does not keep track of the last keys added. Here is a suggestion: use the `collections.deque` data structure. To initialize a list of last 3 appended keys:

```
import collections
most_recent_keys = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
```

When adding to the dictionary, for example, adding `'John', [4]`:

```
d['John'] = [4]
most_recent_keys.append('John')
```

`most_recent_keys` behaves like a regular list, but the size is limitted to 3 elements at initialization.

## Update 2

To use the `most_recent_keys`:

```
# Prints the last 3 items added
for key in sorted(most_recent_keys):
    print('{} = {}'.format(key, d[key]))
```

## Update 3

I understand you want to limit the values of the dictionary to the first three in the list. To do that:

```
import pprint

d = {'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Zanggangwang': [3], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]}

pprint.pprint(d)                                 # Prints everything
print('---')
pprint.pprint({k: v[:3] for k, v in d.items()})  # Prints only first 3
```

Output:

```
{'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9], 'Zanggangwang': [3]}
---
{'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13], 'Zanggangwang': [3]}
```

## Update 4

To save a copy of your dictionary per your quirement:

```
new_d = {k: v[:3] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Now, `new_d` is like the good ol' `d`, but with the values truncated to the first three items. You can then do what you want with it.

Comment: is there a way to limit the key's amount of definitions to 3 the 3 most recent one's appended? @Padraic Cunningham

Comment: A dictionary does not keep track of the last three most recent appended keys. You will have to keep track of it separately. See my update.

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion although It dose not  produce the result I was expecting is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: This limits the amount of keys, I was looking to limit the key's values to the first 3 it comes across.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you want. I am sorry, I cannot help if I don't understand.

Comment: When using your code my dictionary is sorted                                            T = [5]
Tom = [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]
Zanggangwang = [3]                                                                                             It has been limited so that only 3 keys are printed. Whereas I wanted to limit the amount of definitions a key has (Tom = [0,12,13]

Comment: That is excellent cant this be saved to as a variable/ turple out right which I can then sort?

Comment: What do you want to save? The dictionary, or just the values?

Comment: Ideally the dictionary so then I can sort it

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `items`, you are just sorting the keys:

```
d = {'Bill': [23], 'T': [5], 'Zanggangwang': [3], 'Tom': [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]}

# x[0] -> the dict keys
print(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()))
[('Bill', [23]), ('T', [5]), ('Tom', [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]), ('Zanggangwang', [3])]
```

You cannot sort a dictionary so if you want the output to resemble a dict literal you can do it with `str.format` and `str.join` using the sorted items:

```
srtd = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower())


print("{{{}}}".format(", ".join(["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in srtd])))
```

Output:

```
{Bill: [23], T: [5], Tom: [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9], Zanggangwang: [3]}
```

On a sidenote if you want to sort a dicts keys you can just call sorted in the dict, there is no need to call .keys. Also if your strings are all uppercase there is no need to use `str.lower` as the key to sorted.

Comment: How would I get it so that when it prints it simply displays Bill: 25 |T:5 |Tom: 0,12,13,8,9,1,9 | Zanggangwag: 3

Comment: @FenixZ, not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry I submitted the comment by accident. I have edited it to reflect the actual question is was enquiring

Comment: `print(" | ".join(["{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in srtd]))` should do it

Answer (score 1):

Use `collections.OrderedDict`, citing the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

> Since an ordered dictionary remembers its insertion order, it can be used in conjunction with sorting to make a sorted dictionary:
>
> ```
> >>> # regular unsorted dictionary
> >>> d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
>
> >>> # dictionary sorted by key
> >>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[0])) OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
>
> >>> # dictionary sorted by value
> >>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])) OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3), ('apple', 4)])
>
> >>> # dictionary sorted by length of the key string
> >>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[0]))) OrderedDict([('pear', 1), ('apple', 4), ('orange', 2), ('banana', 3)])
> ```

## Update 1

Print the last three inserted in alphabetical order (Python 3):

```
from collections import OrderedDict


d = OrderedDict()
d["Bill"] = [23]
d["T"] = [5]
d["Zanggangwang"] = [3]
d["Tom"] = [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]

for k in sorted(list(reversed(d))[0:3]):
    print(k, d[k])
```

gives:

```
T [5]
Tom [0, 12, 13, 8, 9, 1, 9]
Zanggangwang [3]
```

So that Bill is gone and the other three are ordered by key.  Or if you must, put them back in an OrderDict:

```
OrderedDict({k: d[k] for k in sorted(list(reversed(d))[0:3])})
```

## Update 2

Or if you want to limit the list to three:

```
for k in sorted(list(reversed(d))[0:3]):
    print(k, d[k][:3])
```

that gives:

```
T [5]
Tom [0, 12, 13]
Zanggangwang [3]
```

well, you get the idea...

Comment: I understand that, although how would I get it to just have the values of the 3 most recently appended values?.

Comment: Then you need to start with an OrderedDict so that you can find the most recently added and, in a second step, you order these alphabeticaly.

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: @FenixZ I updated my answer to reflect your new requirements.